# Access Unshipped Orders on Amazon MWS in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

this is our first time using the Amazon MWS (or any API for that matter) and we want to pull all of the unshipped orders from our seller account. We've tried using many different methods (RequestReportRequest, with this link: http://www.amazonsellercommunity.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2370410, and more) but none seem to work. Is there a simple way to access our unshipped orders using C#?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Should be the same in all supported languages.

1. You can request an report using the RequestReport API operation with ReportType being set to _GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA_ . As a response you get a ReportRequestId which you store.
2. Next you periodically check the status of your report request by calling the GetReportRequestList operation, probably with the parameter ReportRequestIdList containing your ReportRequestId. The response tells you in which ReportProcessingStatus the reportRequest is. According to the sellercentral webpage it can take up to 45 minutes to finish a report.
3. Once the ReportProcessingStatus is *DONE*, you need to get the reportId. For this purpose you use the GetReportList operation with the parameter ReportRequestIdList set to your ReportRequestId. The response contains the reportId
4. Finally, you get your report by calling GetReport with the reportId you got in step 3.

For more details, have a look in the [MWS API reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F02%2Fmwsportal%2Fdoc%2Fen_US%2Fbde%2FMWSReportsApiReference._V159025213_.pdf&rct=j&q=mws%20api%20reference%20developer%20guide%20mws&ei=8zyDTuiwOZCq-gawz9DBDw&usg=AFQjCNFv-uKPen_8uWvS-y75DZC4xW2ifA&sig2=L6XJEG5dxSnBkN0JoXJvLA&cad=rja)